# Drawing and animating a triangle in SVG and HTML with user input

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, svg

I have a college project that I've chose to present in HTML, the user would input the three sides of a triangle and the shape would be rendered on the screen. I've made a JavaScript that get these values and create the x and y coordinates drawing the triangle inside the `<canvas>` tag:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function init() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var a = *user input*;
var b = *user input*;
var c = *user input*;
var ox = 450-(a/2);  // 450px since the canvas size is 900px,
var oy = 450+(y3/2); // this aligns the figure to the center
var x3 = ((b*b)+(a*a)-(c*c))/(2*a);
var y3 = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((b*b)-(x3*2)));
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'grad.png';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
ctx.lineWidth   = 3;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
ctx.shadowColor   = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(ox,oy);
ctx.lineTo(a+ox,oy);
ctx.lineTo(ox+x3,oy-y3);
ctx.lineTo(ox,oy);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}
}
</script>

<body onLoad="init();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="900"></canvas><br>
</body>
```

I'm trying to compose a simple scale animation once the page is loaded making the triangle and other shapes to "grow" on the screen. If I use CSS, the entire canvas will scale. Also, I don't know how to make this animation possible since the values are not fixed and using canvas, I would have to animate this frame-by-frame.
Now if I use CSS and SVG, I could use a simple ease-in and scale effect for each element, the problem is that I would have to generate the triangle in a SVG using the values inputted by user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're always going to have a triangle (or polygon) on the screen, I would create the basic framework with SVG/CSS and set the attribute wuth CSS:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="900">
    <defs>
        <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10"/>
            <feMerge> 
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <polygon id="triangle" filter="url(#dropshadow)" />
</svg>
<style>
    #triangle {
        fill: url(grad.png);
        stroke-width: 3px;
        stroke: white;
    }
</style>
```

You could then use much of the same code to set the polygon points:

```
var points = [
    [ox, oy].join(','),
    [a + ox, oy].join(','),
    [ox + x3, oy - y3].join(',')
    ].join(' ');
document.getElementById('triangle').setAttribute('points', points);
```

You can see an example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fTPdy/

Answer (score 2):

A triangle is a polygon with 3 points. Look at [SVG Polygon](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp) documentation.
In JavaScript you can create a polygon like so:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function makeTriangle() {
    shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "points", "5,5 45,45 5,45");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "green");

    svgDocument.documentElement.appendChild(shape);
}
```